# Material UI - TextField as title in Tooltip for Slider knobs, how to make it work?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider, tooltip, textfield

I have MUI `Slider` which uses custom `ValueLabelComponent`. `ValueLabelComponent` in my case it's a MUI `Tooltip` which wraps children (slider knobs) and it appears when you hoover over the knobs. `Tooltip` has property `title` where I pass MUI `TextField` (normally you just pass value in there). The idea is to change min max value not only with slider knobs but by typing in `TextField`.

At the moment I able to render `TextField` inside the `Tooltip`, but I can't type in it.

Here is CodeSandBox - https://codesandbox.io/s/rangeslider-demo-material-ui-forked-fuif4l?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: If I wrap just a div in this tooltip with a title as `TextField` all works.

Comment: I guess it's something similar.. - https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33195